# OpenSearch: How to perform a term aggregation on top of a bucket aggregation?

Tags: opensearch

I have the following structure of data in the index:

```
{
  "identifier": <uuid>,
  "status_one": <string>,
  "status_two": <string>
}
```

Now, I want to first group the data by the `identifier`, and on top of that merge the `status_one` and `status_two` into a single field. I am able to do that using `scripted_metric` aggregation.

Finally, I want to perform `term` aggregation on top of these buckets. i.e, if I directly did `term` aggregation on `status_one` field, it will give us count of records for each of possible `statuses`. I need to do similar for the merged records.

I have tried `stats_bucket` and other types of aggregation, but they are not giving the correct results.